# How can I display the console logs and errors of a headless chrome instance?

Tags: php, symfony, docker, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm working on a Symfony project, which uses Browsershot to export a page to PDF. The exportation is working fine on the server, but when I try to make it work locally inside a Docker container, a lot of ressources (images, CSS etc.) in the PDF are missing and the layout is therefore not correct.

So to troubleshoot it, I would like to access the console logs and errors of the headless chrome instance, which is created by puppeteer and called by Browsershot. 
Does anyone have any experience with this? Is it possible, or does the headless Chrome just not have any development tools like that? I couldn't find anything online, but maybe someone tried it before.

Thanks so much in advance!

This is how Browsershot is called inside the project:

```
Browsershot::html($htmlContent)
                ->noSandbox()
                ->showBrowserHeaderAndFooter()
                ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
                ->headerHtml('<p></p>')
                ->footerHtml($this->getFooter())
                ->showBackground()
                ->emulateMedia('screen')
                ->landscape()
                ->paperSize(210, 297)
                ->margins(10, 10, 10, 10)
                ->windowSize(1200, 850)
                ->save($temp);
```

and I install puppeteer in the Dockerfile like this:

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - && \
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget && \
    sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm puppeteer && \
    sudo chmod -R o+rx /usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium
```

Comment: It is possible to attach to the `console` event of the puppeteer page object and receive all console messages. However, based on the Github repo code of Browsershot, there is no way to get it to report console logs. https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/blob/master/bin/browser.js.